# Не приходит ответ на сложный запрос QPSQL PostgreSQL Qt5

Tags: sql, qt, postgresql, qt5

В консоли всё работает нормально, однако в среде Qt5 такой запрос возвращает результат:

```
SELECT id FROM link WHERE uid_fl = '%1';
```

Другие запросы не возвращают, но выполняются на стороне сервера:

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
QString request = QString(
    "SELECT id FROM link WHERE uid_fl = '%1' AND end_fl IS NULL;"
            )
    .arg(is_uid);
query.exec(request);

while (query.next())
{
    qDebug() << "id" << query.record().value(0).toString();
}
```

То же не работает:

```
"BEGIN;"
"UPDATE link SET end_fl = '%2' "
"WHERE id=( "
"   SELECT id FROM link "
"   WHERE uid_fl = '%1' AND end_fl IS NULL "
"   ORDER BY id LIMIT 1);"
"COMMIT;"
```

Comment: Лаконичность - не всегда благо. Тем более с опечатками. Сейчас в принципе невозможно понять, что и откуда работает, а что нет... *Другие нет, но выполняются* - ну гениальная же фраза...

Comment: @Akina с этим  "AND end_fl IS NULL;" не работает в программе, но работает в консоли.

Comment: Запрос отправляется на сервер? Он добирается до сервера? Выглядит синтаксически правильно? Ответ клиенту отсылается? Правильный? Он до клиента добирается? Неизменённый? и т.п... см. логи, в крайнем случае сниффером. Ищите ту точку, в которой цепочка рвётся.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, посмотрите, что отвечает вам сервер в его логах. Не знаю, как в линуксе, в Win это в папке (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data\log), ну, у четом версии самого постгре. Смотрите файл с последней датой. Исполните запрос и сразу посмотрите, если будет ошибка - там сервер скажет в чем дело. А вообще, мне пришлось писать собственную обвязку вызовов Postgre, поскольку QPSQL - ну просто изумительно по ... с кажем так очень-очень плохо сделана и не возвращает ошибок, о которых сигнализирует сервер БД. Правда тут же лишаешься всех modelview, но я ими и не пользуюсь.